# Phonegap/Cordova calendar plugin for iOS unresponsive

Tags: javascript, ios, jquery-mobile, cordova

I have added the cordova plugin to my app.

command-line:

```
$ cordova plugin add https://github.com/EddyVerbruggen/Calendar-PhoneGap-Plugin.git
$ cordova build
```

The plugin seems to have been added correctly but when I add the javascript to my main.js nothing happens. Main.js:

```
var startDate = new Date(2014,2,15,00,00,0,0,0); // beware: month 0 = january, 11 = december
var endDate = new Date(2014,2,15,00,00,0,0,0);
var place = "";
var notes ="";
var title = "";

function Calendar_Add(){

 var success = function() { alert("Success: " + JSON.stringify("Event Added!")); };
 var error = function(message) { alert("Error: " + "Something went wrong!"); };
 var location = place;

// create an event in a named calendar (iOS only for now)
window.plugins.calendar.createEvent(title,location,notes,startDate,endDate,calendarName,success,error);
```

}

index.html:

```
<a href="#" onClick="Calendar_Add()" class="ui-btn ui-btn-inline">Add to Calendar</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

Add deviceready event. It should work.

```
   function Calendar_Add(){
     var startDate = new Date(2014,2,15,00,00,0,0,0); // beware: month 0 = january, 11 = december
    var endDate = new Date(2014,2,15,00,00,0,0,0);
     var place = "";
     var notes ="";
     var title = "";
     var success = function() { alert("Success: " + JSON.stringify("Event Added!")); };
     var error = function(message) { alert("Error: " + "Something went wrong!"); };
     var location = place;

    // create an event in a named calendar (iOS only for now)
    window.plugins.calendar.createEvent(title,location,notes,startDate,endDate,calendarName,success,error);
}

document.addEventListener("deviceready", Calendar_Add, false);
```

Answer (score 0):

createEvent does not take a calendarName param, use calendarNameInNamedCalendar if you need your own calendar.

Answer (score -1):

look at [this](http://plugins.telerik.com/cordova/plugin/calendar), I do run

I use and work very well cal.createEventInteractively